# jQuery: Difference between these two approcaches of writing code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `jQuery` `bootstrap` in my application. I have the following dialog box code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Share With Friends</h4>
      </div>
      <form class='shareForm' id='dialogForm' role='form'>        
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Update page title</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                <span class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">asahjk akshak shaks jhk</div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">          
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I will use this dialog multiple times. Now I have two choice to use this:

1. I should keep all this code as string `e.g var myDialog = above code` in some `js` file and called that `myDialog` variable whenever I need.
2. I should generate above code dynamically every time it is called using something like `$("<div/>")`.

Now I want to know what is the difference between these two in terms of performance, memory usage because what i am guessing that in first case it will consume memory more as it will be big string. In 2nd case creating everything dynamically will be a tedious job.

Answer (score 1):

You could also investigate a HTML templating engine of which their are many. This has the added benefits of keeping your HTML markup out of your JavaScript logic, i.e no horrible long html in JavaScript variables that are hard to maintain, while still being able to reference the code from a JavaScript file that you can reference whenever you want. Not to mention being able to dynamically populate data without needing to recreate your HTML markup.

John Resig came up with a [solution](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) and great explanation several years ago which has since been expanded upon by many developers implementing their own templating solution. [The Template Engine Chooser](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/) may help you in selecting a templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just put it in a seperate file and include that whenever it is needed. That way you are not dependand on Javascript for this code.

Comment: Yah I can use in separate file. I want to know which approach that i mentioned is good

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not just a small div, I would keep that in a hidden div on the page where you need it, and just change its visibility.
That's the simplest, most discoverable and readable way in my opinion, and you don't need to generate it every time...

Comment: but i want to use in many page.So in your way i will have to paste same code everywhere

Comment: then you would have it on a separate partial, and include that partial where you need it.
Another solution is to expose the partial at a url and load it when you need to show it. You set a long cache so that you'd pay the tansfer only once, and if you need to manipulate some text on it, you can still do it before you display the modal... There isn't really a better solution. they all provide the same value to your user...